# Cloud Firestore / Firebase bandwidth very high

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, video-processing, bandwidth

I have been using cloud Firestore for a month now and quite happy with how things are going so far except for the one factor and that's of course the billing. My app is a short videos app which is using too much of bandwidth. Each video is around 2MB on average. After compressing, that gets uploaded. There are around 700 users who are using the app right now and I wasn't expecting the billing to grow so much with such a small user base. The billing is still under my FREE trial and is not much for me but in future with this rate, it's sure going to empty my pocket.

I am using cloud Firestore and the storage too. My initial thought is to use another CDN network (I guess Firebase is not a CDN too) - perhaps, Bunnycdn to host the videos. Now, the question is if I switch to Bunnycdn or another CDN storage provider, will the Firebase bandwidth get reduced ? I think the high bandwidth is mainly because of videos & thus, if I switch to another hosting provider/CDN, the Firebase bandwidth won't be this high, am I correct in this approach ? Of course, there will be billing from Bunnycdn or so, but I guess their bandwidth usage price is way too affordable than Firebase.

Users upload and watch videos in the app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So after a month of development and having discussions with the Firebase team, I moved all the data from cloud storage to a CDN provider - bunnycdn. I am not receiving any high bills from Firebase storage now. Most of my queries seem to be good and they are still under the daily limit.

If anyone finds this useful - kindly do not use Firebase storage if you are going to have high data storage and high bandwidth usage. Right now, I have only the DB collecitons and documents over firestore. All data of videos moved to bunnycdn and this is showing quite a good results to me.

Comment: Is it possible for you to write about it? How did you add bunnycdn with storage as a CDN?

Comment: just curious. Have you try or thought about Google Cloud CDN on top of Cloud Storage?

Comment: @rohan koshti, Can you please give instruction / links[tutorial] about how to achieve this?

Comment: hi, can you please guide me how can I use the media from bunnycdn into my mobile application? I am finding it hard to comprehend

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore billing is a bit interesting, you typically do not pay for bandwidth for your Firestore access unless you have selected a regional centre (multi-regional centres are your friend for billing). More detail here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#network

Accordingly I would not expect your Firestore bill to reduce because, all things being equal, you should still be making the same number of access events and using the same amount of database storage. There are some techniques you can use to reduce your reads (which should be the vast majority of access events) like caching non-sensitive records on the client device and only fetching new records. I use a 'timestampLastUpdated' record so that only new records and recently updated are fetched.

I would expect your Cloud Storage bill to be eliminated and replaced by the bill of your new CDN.